# Allow dynamic drag drop permissions using arrays

Tags: java, gwt-ext, treepanel

I have created two trees in gwt-ext one contains the values of nodes that can be dragged and other the nodes which can be dropped on. The problem being i am not able to set only a particular set of leaves mentioned in the array, from a tree to be dragged on other tree while the leaves which are not in the array cannot be dragged. I have enabled drag drop on the tree and then manually allow a leaf to disable drag but its not working. Tried it using the **setallowdrag()** method and also using **setTreeAttribute("allowDrag",false)** but don't know why it just doesn't work. Please help.

```
TreeNode n22=treePanel.getNodeById("ynode-121");
n22.setTreeAttribute("allowDrag","false");
n22.setAllowDrag(false);
```